# Adding google analytics to angular 16 app with no app.module

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I have an Angular 16 app that uses all standalone components and am trying to set up google analytics. I'm guessing [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-analytics) is the one we need to use so I installed it and added the `NgxGoogleAnalyticsModule` to the `providers` array in my `main.ts` file like I do all the other things we'd normally add to our `app.module` in older versions of angular.  As of right now I'm getting the following error.

> Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider | EnvironmentProviders'.ts(2322)

I've been searching around the internet trying to find the proper way to add it to a standalone app but everything I come across is pretty old.  Is there another way I should be doing this or another package I don't know about that I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [`importProvidersFrom`](https://angular.io/api/core/importProvidersFrom) in the `app.config.ts` like shown below!

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxGoogleAnalyticsModule } from 'ngx-google-analytics';
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    ...
    importProvidersFrom(
      NgxGoogleAnalyticsModule.forRoot('enter analytics id here!')
    ),
  ],
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-npnlmc?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.config.ts&title=node.new%20Starter) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`